# Jquery hide is not working in my Dialog box close span

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all').hide();
```

this is the hide for my Jquery dialog close 'X' span.. this is not working in my case.

I am trying to hide that Close becuase its not showing me in my dialog when I resize my dialog then its showing me.. some reason my CSS not showing me that Close button correctly on my POPUP.

Can any body help me out.

here is my code and CSS.

```
  $("#window").dialog({
          resizable: true,
          height: 180,
          title: titles,
          width: 500,
          modal: true,
          open: function () {
              $('.ui-widget-overlay').show();
              $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all').hide();
          },
          buttons: {
              "OK": function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
                  if (redirectURL) {
                      window.location = redirectURL;
                  }
              }
          }
      });
```

here is my CSS.

```
<style>
.ui-widget-overlay {
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10;
 }
</style>
```

Can any body tell me how to  show My Close 'X' correctly on my dialog or I need to hide that Close 'X'

thanks

Comment: Based on your question, it is not clear what exactly your close button is doing. It's possible to fix the display issue without hiding the close button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector for multiple CSS classes has a full stop between the two, like this:

```
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close.ui-corner-all').hide();
```